# How to add records to database using a joined table - codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, forms, codeigniter, join

I made a form for adding factories to my database. this works great but i can't show my factories on the page because they're in a joined table, but when i submit the page it does not add an id to the joined table so the factory won't be shown at the page.

the joined table looks like this:

```
bedrijfcategorieen
------------------
idbedrijfcat
idbedrijven
idcategorieen
```

Where idbedrijven is the id for my factories table.

My controller function for adding factories:

```
function bedrijven()
{
    $data['options'] = $ddmenu;
    $this->load->view('members/header');
    $this->load->view('members/editform', $data);
    $this->load->view('members/footer');
}

function addbedrijven()
{
    $this->members_model->addbedrijf();
    redirect('members/index');
}
```

my model function for adding factories:

```
function addbedrijf()
{
    $data = array(
       'idbedrijven' => $idbedrijven,
       'Bedrijfsnaam' => $this->input->post('Bedrijfsnaam'),
       'Postcode' => $this->input->post('Postcode'),
       'Plaats' => $this->input->post('Plaats'),
       'Telefoonnummer' => $this->input->post('Telefoonnummer'),
       'Email' => $this->input->post('Email'),
       'Website' => $this->input->post('Website'),
       'Profiel' => $this->input->post('Profiel'),
       'Adres' => $this->input->post('Adres'),
       'logo' => $this->input->post('logo')
    );

    $this->db->insert('bedrijven', $data);
}
```

i would like to add my factories trough the joined table. so it would be easier to add categories to the factories too.

I tried `where('bedrijfcategorieen.idbedrijven = idbedrijven` but it did not work.

---

**table scheme**

```
factories
---------
idfactories
factoryname
adress
postcode
country
telephone
...
...


categories
----------
idcategories
category

factorycategories
-----------------
idfactorycat
idfactories
idcategories
```

---

Comment: Can you add your insert query?

Comment: i allready posted my insert query. it's the model function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right - you want to add records to two different tables via JOIN. This is not possible. You'll have two write separate insert statements for both the tables.

Take a look at the Active Record's documentation http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/helpers.html and read about `$this->db->insert_id();` This may give you clues about how to write your insert statement.

Comment: can't get it to work because the documentation is very small.

Comment: I think, you should explain in details what you're trying to achieve. The tables' scheme would help. 2 tables cannot be in joined state. Join is clause of select statement that just combines records from two or more tables and returns results, but the tables behind are still separate, so you'll have to add records to both the tables. As far as I understand - you have a select statement with join on 2 tables and get combined record. Then you insert a record in one of the tables and that's why you don't get this record back, because there is no related entry on the other. Am I right?

Comment: i will post the table scheme. i work with 3 tables. 1 for categories 1 for factories and a factorycategories table. i posted it in my Question.